# DNS issues when joining new wifi networks

Tags: macos, network, wifi, dns

Lately, I've been having a bit of a strange issue where my MacBook Air M2 cannot resolve DNS for a while after connecting to new wifi networks. Several other devices work fine on the same networks (phone, tablet, a linux laptop). This is often more problematic on public wifi networks when traveling - cafes, airports, hotels etc.

I've tried with manual DNS servers, automatic DNS via DHCP etc to no avail. I can even ping and ssh to direct IP addresses, even connect to VPNs but just can't resolve hostnames.

After about 5-6 minutes of waiting, the DNS resolution seems to just begin working again with no explanation. I was wondering how I can go about debugging what the issue is.

Comment: Please boot in safe mode and see whether you can reproduce the problem.